# Lyft Api: How do I get a current ride?

Tags: php

How do I get a current ride information from an authenticated driver? Is this possible from web hooks or is there anyway to do this? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: if its not in the documentation, i dont know what you expect us to say

Comment: @IdontDownVote I'm hoping there is a work around or an un-documented way.